# Deserializar byte[] en System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin-studio

me pongo en contacto a ver si hay suerte y alguien se ha pegado con este problema antes.

Tengo un byte[] el cual contiene serializado un hashtable, y busco deserializarlo en xamarin forms, es decir, deserializarlo para android, ios y windows_uwp para poder utilizar su contenido para unos ejercicios.

Buscando encontré  que la clase que se podría utilizar para deserializar era "BinaryFormatter", problema, no es compatible con windows_uwp.

Mi segunda opción fue la de utilizar el método System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer, con el siguiente codigo:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Buffer);
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer XML = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("System.Collections.Hashtable"));
lst = (System.Collections.Hashtable)XML.Deserialize(mem);
```

el problema es que me devuelve la siguiente excepción que no se como solucionar:

The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

A ver si hay suerte y alguien puede echarme un cable con este problema

Comment: he probado a descomprimir el bytearray y tampoco ayudó

Answer (score 0):

Te podria ayudar este metodo para deserializar genérico utilizado como bien lo dices [BinaryFormater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)

```
   private static T ByteArrayToObject<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            T obj = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Para utilizarlo puedes hacer algo asi...

```
var hashTableUnserialize = ByteArrayToObject<Hashtable>(dataSerialize);
```

Arme un ejemplo completo que te puede servir de ayuda  o guia

- SerializeObjectToByteArray.cs > Serialize and Deserialize Object To Byte Array (with use Generics) / Serializar y deserializar object to byte array (utilizando Generics)
  https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/1612068fb0622fd8081ea930d6dee793

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, he probado directamente tu ejemplo para ver como funciona, y luego e intentado añadir mi bytearray, y me da la siguiente excepción en el momento de  T obj = 
(T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(ms);                                                                     
Excepción producida: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' en mscorlib.dll
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' en mscorlib.dll
No se puede encontrar el ensamblado 'PluginDesign, Version=1.1.1.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Tu coméntame más de ese componente "PluginDesign". Lo tienes referenciado en tu proyecto? Estás utilizando una clase de dicho assembly. Cuál es?

Comment: Lo consultare y te lo comento, pero no se si tendré acceso a esa información hoy la verdad...a ver si hay suerte y puedo decirte algo cuanto antes.

Comment: Puedes armar un ejemplo del código funcional y lo cuelgas en GitHub (y lo pegas como parte de.tu pregunta) para ver y ejecutar un mini ejemplo así te podemos ayudar mejor. Ya que deserializar binariamente es el código que respondí en el ejemplo. De allí necesitas obviamente la clase a deserializar (conocer dicha clase para inatanciarla en la deserializar ion)

Comment: el código seria este, pero no tengo la clase para deslateralizar, y creo que es imposible conocerla solo mirando ese codigo. Si fuera un xml se podria, pero creo que siendo un hashtable no es posible. Si lo llegaras a probar imagino que verias la excepcion que comente en el primer comentario.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f466ce7a9622666898b3bb1e7e3bcec2

Comment: Si ves el código en texto del objecto serializado veras que utiliza un objecto en el Hashtable dentro un objecto que es
PluginDesign.ScreenElements.SequentialElement.SequentialElementGC, PluginDesign, Version=1.1.1.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
O sea necesitas dicha clase en que se encuentra en el assembly PluginDesign, Version=1.1.1.35
 (respondi como ejemplo tambien en tu Gist que compartiste)

Comment: podría generar esa clase de forma manual para arreglarlo con ese apaño, o ese assembly será un dll si o si? porque son clases en .net que no creo que sean compatibles con mi proyecto en c#

Comment: Y... si? Podrias pero deberias conocer la propiedades de la clase SequentialElementGC y obviamente no tendrias los metodos que contiene.Es decir puedes crear un proyecto que se llame PluginDesign y que contenga la clase SequentialElementGC y lo referncias a que estas deserializando y alli no te dara dicho error... PERO! tendrias que adivinar que propiedades tenia la clase destino (y obviamente no tendras los metodos). Asi que en definitiva o adivinas que tenia dicha clase o el requerimiento que tienes en tu proyecto/job deberia contemplar este inconveniente de no tener la clase de destino

Comment: Ademas agregue en tu ejemplo https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f466ce7a9622666898b3bb1e7e3bcec2 al final lo que devuelve si generas un proyecto "dummy" con el nombre de la clase a deserializar

Comment: Podrías copiar el proyecto completo que has creado? como apaño quizás podría servirme ya que la clase que necesito solo tiene un id, un bool y poco más. Entonces si consigo a parte del id, el bool yo creo que podría valer

Comment: Podrías copiar el proyecto completo que has creado? por así decirse el contenido es una lista de listas, con un ID y un BOOL que indican si es el elemento que me interesa. Varias listas con diferentes IDs y bool asociados a cada ID. No se si me explico. Por eso a lo mejor editando esa clase que has creado a lo mejor se puede sacar el contenido

Comment: He dejado un comentario con la clase que quizás sea la que interesa, no se si servirá

Comment: Deje un ejemplo en https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet en la carpeta DeserializeObjectFromStringThatIsAnByteArray

Comment: Puede que ya no veas este hilo, a ver si hay suerte. Porque puede ser que no se obtenga el contenido del hashtable? que se obtenga la key pero no lo que es el contenido en si? alguna idea de que probar?